# Google Docs Viewer have problem in MultiSite sub-blogs

Tags: multisite

An example file:
http://twentyeleven.korkmaz.biz/files/2012/09/example.docx

and here is same file but direct url without ms-files.php:
http://twentyeleven.korkmaz.biz/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2012/09/example.docx

Its same file. Just first one is getting call with ms-files.php. Problem is
first file is not working in google docs viewer: 
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://twentyeleven.korkmaz.biz/files/2012/09/example.docx

giving this error:

> Sorry, we are unable to generate a view of the document at this time.
>   Please try again later. You can also try to download the original
>   document by clicking here.

But if i call same file with directly without ms-files.php:
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://twentyeleven.korkmaz.biz/wp-content/blogs.dir/3/files/2012/09/example.docx

Its working! So for some reason wordpress multisite is corrupting files in sub-blogs. There is no problem in main blog because main blog's files getting direct call and not using ms-files.php

So how can i fix this? If you think i cant fix it, how can i get real path url from WordPress generated /files/ url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only fix for 3.4.2 involves hacking a core file. The issue is already corrected in the upcoming version 3.5.

Edit wp-includes/functions.php. Around line 1810, you'll find this:

```
'doc|docx' => 'application/msword',
```

Change that to this:

```
'doc' => 'application/msword',
```

The docx file extension is actually already handled properly later down in the file, line 1819:

```
'docx|dotx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml',
```

So it will work properly once you remove the spurious extension.

Again, hacking core files is a bad thing, but seeing as the refactorization in WordPress 3.5 corrects the issue already, and there's no way to do this in a plugin or theme or even with a proper drop-in, I think that this specific case might justify it.

Answer (score 3):

The resulting file is identical regardless of the link that you use. I downloaded the file via each link and compared the files, they are identical.

So the conclusion is that it's a matter of headers. What I get from the ms-blogs version of the url is:

```
Content-Type: application/msword
```

Versus what I get from direct link:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Which appears to be a type which Google Docs understands.

My concluson is that the MIME type that WordPress provides for this file, `application/msword`, is not one that Google Docs understands.

You can fix this by filtering `upload_mimes`, and changing the result MIME type for .docx files to match the correct one that Google Docs understands:

```
function my_filter_upload_mimes( $mimes ) {
     $mimes['doc|docx'] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
     return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_filter_upload_mimes' );
```

WordPress uses this filter in the function [`get_allowed_mime_types()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L1772), which is used by [`wp_check_filetype()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L1679) to determine the output MIME type in [`wp-includes/ms-files.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/ms-files.php#L32)

**Update**

`wp-includes/ms-files.php` uses `SHORTINIT`, so themes are not loaded, and thus the above code will not work if you place it in your theme code.

<del>Plugins, on the other hand, will still be loaded even with `SHORTINIT` enabled.</del>

*(Edit by Otto: This is incorrect, SHORTINIT prevents plugin loading. See wp-settings.php, around line 95 for where the SHORTINIT flag cuts off the loading process, and note that plugins load after that. The following code will not work.)*

*(Edit by Bendoh: D'oh! I had commented out the SHORTINIT declaration while testing and thus my solution **did** work, but you're correct that it won't work without mucking with core. I removed the code below as it doesn't actually work. Otto's answer is correct)*

Comment: Files are identical because there's **only one** file. The first link (`files/2012/09/example.docx`) is redirected via `.htaccess` to the 2nd link.

Comment: That is exactly my point. The issue is that the webserver is providing a different value for the `Content-Type` HTTP response header than what WordPress is returning. The question stated that "WordPress multisite is corrupting files in sub-blogs."  I was showing that this is not the case and the difference is only in the response header, which is what is throwing off Google Docs.

Comment: i tried that before but didnt work, you can see result here: `http://twentyeleven.korkmaz.biz/files/2012/09/example1.docx`
I added your code, uploaded same file again after added code, it says `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` format in media panel but still header is `application/msword` when you call it via /files/ url

Comment: Here is screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/6wcfN.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't work because the ms-files.php file does a SHORTINIT, which doesn't load plugins at all, including network enabled ones. You can't fix this with a plugin or a theme. However, this specific mime type was added in WordPress 3.5, as of 4 weeks ago: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21541